# Why void* as template parameter works as function parameter but not template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have two version of `my_begin`:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value>::type* = 0>
typename std::decay<T>::type my_begin(T& array) {
    return array;
}
```

and

```
template<typename T>
typename std::decay<T>::type my_begin(T& array, 
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value>::type* = 0) {
    return array;
}
```

However the first one does not work and gives error:

```
int a[10];
int* a_it = my_begin(a);
```

error:

```
main.cpp:17:30: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

main.cpp:16:80: error: could not convert template argument '0' to 'std::enable_if<true, void>::type* {aka void*}'

 template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value>::type* = 0>
```

But the second one works. When I change 0 in the first one to nullptr, it works too (but still not working for NULL). I do understand that in template it requires explicit casting (in this case, from `int` to `void*`, but why the second one does not require it?

Another question, if I remove the whitespace between `*` and `=`, it also failed. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

§14.1 [temp.param]/p4 says:

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.

Read literally, this disallows `void*` template parameters altogether. `void*` is an *object pointer type* but isn't a pointer to object type (§3.9.2 [basic.compound]/p3):

> The type of a pointer to `void` or a pointer to an object type is
>   called an *object pointer type*. [ *Note*: A pointer to `void` does
>   not have a pointer-to-object type, however, because `void` is not an
>   object type. —*end note* ]

If we assume it's a defect and that the standard really meant to say "object pointer type", then using `0` and company is still disallowed by §14.3.2 [temp.arg.nontype]/p5 (emphasis added):

> The following conversions are performed on each expression used as a
>   non-type *template-argument*. If a non-type *template-argument* cannot be
>   converted to the type of the corresponding *template-parameter* then the
>   program is ill-formed.
>
> - [...]
> - for a non-type *template-parameter* of type pointer to object, qualification conversions (4.4) and the array-to-pointer conversion
>     (4.2) are applied; if the *template-argument* is of type `std::nullptr_t`,
>     the null pointer conversion (4.10) is applied. [ *Note*: **In particular,
>     neither the null pointer conversion for a zero-valued integer literal
>     (4.10) nor the derived-to-base conversion (4.10) are applied.** Although
>     0 is a valid *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* of
>     integral type, it is not a valid *template-argument* for a non-type
>     *template-parameter* of pointer type. However, both `(int*)0` and `nullptr`
>     are valid *template-arguments* for a non-type template-parameter of type
>     “pointer to int.” —*end note* ]

`= 0` works for function default arguments because those are subject to the normal conversion rules, which allows an integer literal with value 0 to convert to a null pointer, rather than the special rules for template arguments.

---

> if I remove the whitespace between * and =, it also failed. Why is that?

Maximum munch. If the whitespace is removed, `*=` is a single token (the compound assignment operator). Just like in C++03 when you had to put a space between the `>`s in `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`.